Как исправить при border-radius появление полу-белой формы
Долго не могу понять как это исправить, помогите


#form {
  margin-top: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.form-text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 750;
  color: #000;
}

#user_name,
#user_phone {
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 18px;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
<form id="form">
  <div class="form-text">Оформление</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="user_name" placeholder="Имя">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="user_phone" placeholder="Номер телефона">
  </div>
  <button id="send">Заказать</button>
</form>





может вы хотя бы стили покажете или будем играть в угадайку?


Оформление






Заказать
#form {
margin-top: 48px;
display: none;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.form-text{
margin-bottom: 12px;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 750;
color: #ffffff;
}
#user_name, #user_phone {
outline: none;
margin-top: 6px;
background-color: #222222;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 256px;
height: 18px;
}
input {
outline: none;
}

input, textarea, button по умолчанию имеют border.
Т.е. нужно сбросить это значение на 0 (или none) чтобы вовсе его "отключить".


#form {
  margin-top: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#form input {
  border: 0;
}

.form-text {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 750;
  color: #000;
}

#user_name,
#user_phone {
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 6px;
  background-color: #222;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 256px;
  height: 18px;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}
<form id="form">
  <div class="form-text">Оформление</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="user_name" placeholder="Имя">
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="user_phone" placeholder="Номер телефона">
  </div>
  <button id="send">Заказать</button>
</form>




А вообще, очень сильно советую подключать к проекту так называемый reset.css, очень полезная штука.
А так же, не менее полезным будет использовать Devtools вашего браузера (Chrome, например), там в целом можно узнать что "навешивается" на определённый элемент от ваших стилей, других или браузера.

За первую часть ответа плюсик, а reset - гадость.
